# curl ничего не возвращает

Tags: php, apache, curl

На сервере (Windows 2012) стоит Apache + PHP.
Пытаюсь подключится к Qiwi API по curl.
Этот же код без каких либо изменений на локалке работает.
PHP ошибок не выдает.

Просто в ответ на какую-либо функцию мне в ответ прилетает пустота.
Прописал '*echo $result;*' после строки '*$result = curl_exec($ch);*' и там ничего не было. Пустота. 
Обычно API при неверных данных возвращает ошибку, а тут ничего.

Я подключил модуль curl в php. При проверке в консоли, phpinfo() результаты говорят о том, что модуль на месте.

'echo curl_error($ch);' вернул : **'SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chainblet'**;

Дайте совет в чем искать причину всех бед и что можно попробовать. Ниже прилагаю рабочую часть класса (*полную версию класса можете увидеть по ссылке внизу поста*) и скриншот с описанием модуля curl из php.

[image: Характеристики модуля curl]

```
class Qiwi {
private $_phone;
private $_token;
private $_url;

function __construct($phone, $token) {
    $this->_phone = $phone;
    $this->_token = $token;
    $this->_url   = 'https://edge.qiwi.com/';
}
private function sendRequest($method, array $content = [], $post = false) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    if ($post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->_url . $method);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($content));
    } else {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->_url . $method . '/?' . http_build_query($content));
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->_token,
        'Host: edge.qiwi.com'
    ]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($result, 1);
}
}
```

[Ссылка на полную версию Qiwi API class на GitHub](https://github.com/Shnapik/Qiwi-Api-Class-PHP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)
```